# Parsing XML with no style information?

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a simple XML parse from web, but I seem to be hitting some roadblocks. If I try to do a classic XML parse:

```
library(XML)
url <- c("http://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/173346?stats=1")
xml <- xmlTreeParse(url, encoding = "UTF-8", isURL=TRUE)
```

I get:

```
Unknown encoding "UTF-8"
Error: 1: Unknown encoding "UTF-8"
```

Even though it seems like I specified the encoding already. Looking at the XML from the site, it says across the top that it doesn't have any style information, but displays the document tree anyway. Then, if I try to do an htmlParse instead,

```
file <- htmlTreeParse(url, encoding = "UTF-8", isURL=TRUE)
```

I get:

```
Error in which(value == defs) : 
argument "code" is missing, with no default
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find it easier in the long run to move to `rvest` and `xml2`:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

pg <- read_xml("http://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/173346?stats=1")

xml_nodes(pg, xpath="//name") %>% xml_text()

xml_nodes(pg, xpath="//description") %>% xml_text()

xml_nodes(pg, xpath="//boardgamehonor") %>% xml_text()

xml_nodes(pg, xpath="//name[@primary='true' and @sortindex=1]") %>% xml_text()

html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//ranks/rank") %>% 
  xml_attrs() %>% 
  map(~as_data_frame(as.list(.))) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One additional question: in the <ranks></ranks> field at the end, there is info, but doesn't seem to be returnable. Is there a way to return the xml strings from the <ranks> tag?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to brush up on HTML/XML a bit. these are fairly basic questions you're asking as an extension and have fairly easy to find answers but that assumes knowledge of HTML/XML. You'll be better off in the end with a solid foundational understanding of that.